# How do I keep chrome from searching for URLs that begin with http

Tags: google-chrome

When I'm developing and testing locally in Chrome, every time I type (or paste) in "http://0.0.0.0:8000" Chrome tries to *search* for that instead of just *going there*.

How can I keep it from searching for it? Usually in the auto-complete options the thing I want (literally the exact thing I just typed in) shows up as the *second* option down (has a little page icon to the left of it instead of a magnifying glass). "Just hit the down arrow and select that one" isn't an acceptable answer.

I've tried deleting the auto-complete option using (on a mac) fn+shft+delete, but, it won't delete it (because it isn't a history item, that trick only works with history items in your auto-complete list).

Anything that begins with "http://" I want Chrome to go to there, not try to search. How can I make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address, so Chrome has no where to go, which is why it is searching instead of going.

Comment: @heavyd that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal as it has other implications (and probably should be a comment) but:

> I created a Search Engine named "No", gave it the keyword "null" and set the url to "http://%s".  Then set it to be the default search engine.  This effectively disables search.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gX-XROa4f6c)

Or install a different version as I believe it didn't use to do this... EG, I just tested it using Chrome Canary version 42 and it does not perform the search, it took me to a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same behaviour with other, not fully-formed adresses, such as an internal confluence instance on `http://wiki`. Entering just 'wiki' would lead me to a search page. Adding a backslash (`wiki/`) resolved this for me.

Another solution might be to not use an ip adress, but `http://localhost:8000`.